# Remove duplicate attribute(ngModel, value) in angular forms

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-ngmodel, angular-forms

I have made a `DatePickerDirective` which is working fine as required. But in order to sync the value of the particular input field on which this directive sits, I have to use value and ngModel attribute both. I wish to use only ngModel how can this be achieved gracefully.

**Form Element**

```
 <input appDatePicker type="text" required name="title" value="{{holiday.off_date}}" [(ngModel)]="holiday.off_date" class="form-control"
                       placeholder="01/01/2018">
```

**Component File**

```
export class HolidayCreateComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  holiday = new HolidayModel('', '');

}
```

**Model File**

```
export class HolidayModel {

  constructor(public occasion: string, public off_date: string) {
  }

}
```

**Directive File**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, forwardRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from '@angular/forms';

declare const $: any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDatePicker]',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting:
      forwardRef(() => DatePickerDirective),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class DatePickerDirective implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  value: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {

  }


  ngOnInit() {
    $(this.el.nativeElement).datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      todayHighlight: true,
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    }).on('change', e => this._onChange(e.target.value));
  }


  private _onChange(_) {
  }

  private _onTouched(_) {
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this._onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this._onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
  }

  writeValue(val: string): void {
    this.value = val;
  }


}
```

The problem is whenever i try to manipulate value of date field from component i need use both value and ngmodel. I think this is not right can be improved. Is there anything which i forgot.

**NOTE:** the value and ngModel is required only where directive is used. If the input has no directive then ngModel works just perfect. I want the same behavior for the element with directive.

Answer (score 0):

`value` simply means the [**initial**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp), default value of the datepicker. `ngModel` is the two-way bound object that has your data afther the user pick's the date. Your code is fine as it is.

Comment: But if I don’t use directive then only ngmodel works for me. It’s only the case when directive is used. Whenever a date is picked from date picker the change is not triggered and hence ngmodel doesn’t bind to the variable.

Comment: it might be becouse you subscribe on your directive to the change event `.on('change', e => this._onChange(e.target.value));`
You insert the nativeElement.value to the onChange function.