# Disabled property not working after adding directive in Angular, working if no directive is present

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-forms

I have a input field which is not getting disabled after adding directive. If the directive is removed it works perfectly fine.

```
 <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Date<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-7">
          <input type="text"
               appDatePicker
               [disabled]="currentOperation === 'view' || currentOperation ==='delete'"
               required
               value="{{holiday.off_date}}"
               name="description"
               [(ngModel)]="holiday.off_date"
               class="form-control"
               placeholder="01/01/2014">
      </div>
  </div>
```

**Directive**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, forwardRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from '@angular/forms';

declare const $: any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDatePicker]',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting:
      forwardRef(() => DatePickerDirective),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class DatePickerDirective implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  value: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {

  }


  ngOnInit() {
    $(this.el.nativeElement).datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      todayHighlight: true,
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    }).on('change', e => this._onChange(e.target.value));
  }


  private _onChange(_) {
  }

  private _onTouched(_) {
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this._onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this._onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
  }

  writeValue(val: string): void {
    this.value = val;
  }


}
```

I fear this problem is linked with the question I asked before. Link to that question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49828724/remove-duplicate-attributengmodel-value-in-angular-forms/49829049#49829049)

I have just tried disabled property, maybe other attributes will also not work.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching i found out that ControlValueAccessor has one method which can be used to disable the state. The following can be achieved by adding this.

```
  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    $(this.el.nativeElement).attr('disabled', isDisabled);
  }
```